# script to download all files from a drop down list

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to write a script (on [this](https://www2.calrecycle.ca.gov/LGCentral/DisposalReporting/Origin/ExportByCounty) webpage) to select the first county, click `Generate Excel` (the file will download), select the second county, click `Generate Excel`, and so forth for all the counties.

What I have so far:

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
 driver.get("https://www2.calrecycle.ca.gov/LGCentral/DisposalReporting/Origin/ExportByCounty")

driver.set_window_size(1920, 1048)
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID, "CountyID")
dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = '[Alameda]']").click()
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "CountyID")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).click_and_hold().perform()
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "CountyID")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "CountyID")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).release().perform()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "SearchButton").click()
```

The issue is that I need to change `"//option[. = '[Alameda]']"` to each county which would be time-consuming. Is there a way I can cycle through a list of the counties? Or I can select all the available counties?

THANK YOU for your time and help with this. I value any feedback/ideas/comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the `option` tag inside the `select` element and loop through it.

This should work for you (tested on Windows 10; Chrome version 100):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D://chromedriver/100/chromedriver.exe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www2.calrecycle.ca.gov/LGCentral/DisposalReporting/Origin/ExportByCounty"

driver.get(url)

select_el = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[@id="CountyID"]')))
counties = select_el.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'option')
total_counties = len(counties)

# len - 1 because the 1st option is blank
print(f"Total counties: {total_counties - 1}")
btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@id="SearchButton"]')

for i in range(1, len(counties)):
    print(f"Clicking County - {counties[i].text}")
    counties[i].click()
    btn.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```